# Collect running time of each JUnit test

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jenkins

Is there a way to easily collect running times of each unit test (for example with either  surefire or some Jenkins plugin) so that I could for example list my Top 10 slowest unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is installing Sonar as a plugin to Jenkins. Sonar can show the unit tests in running time order. And of course it contains a whole lot of other useful info, I don't know how we managed before :)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything built into Jenkins that would do this, but you could add a build step that processes the JUnit report XML file and pulls out the execution times, then format the data into HTML and use the [HTML Publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) to display the results on the build page.